# Vue.js how to push array into the state array

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Firstly, i could be write bad title. But i dont know how can explane my problem.

I have array in vuex state and it's empty. I am filling this array when page is open.

```
 0:
    description: "ll"
    level: null
    name: "asd"
    parentTaskId: null
    state: null
    subTaskList: null
    taskId: 100
```

it's the object fields in my array.
i want to fill subTaskList when i add new subTask but i am gettin error.

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        tasks : [],
    },

    mutations: {
        addToTask: function(state, newTask){
            console.log(newTask.taskId)
            if(newTask.parentTaskId != null){

                for(var index = 0; count < state.tasks.length ; index++){
                    if(state.tasks[index].taskId == newTask.parentTaskId){
                        if(state.tasks.subTaskList != null){
                            state.tasks.subTaskList.push(newTask)
                        }else{
                            console.log(this.state.tasks[index])
                        }
                    }else{
                        state.tasks.push(newTask);
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log(state.tasks)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your state is **`null`** at the beginning, so you cannot use method .push() of undefined. Better initialize those lists with empty array:

```
 0:
    description: "ll"
    level: null
    name: "asd"
    parentTaskId: null
    state: {
      tasks: []
      subtasks: []
    }
    subTaskList: []
    taskId: 100
```

**`null.push()`** will throw this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null

One more thing if `tasks` is an array, so then you cannot do such a thing: `state.tasks.subTaskList` it will mean that you are treating `tasks` field like an object. If tasks can contain tasks and subtasks, then it is better to transform it into an object:

```js
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        tasks: {
          tasks: [],
          subTasks: []
        }
    },
```

But you can create 2 separated fields on Vuex state one for tasks second for subtasks:

```js
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        tasks: [],
        subTasks: []
    },
```